# filtering dict type in python into csv

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing, dictionary

I have set of these dictionary in text file : 
[dataset 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjzeX.png)

I also have these set of data in another text file : 
[dataset 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29SBQ.png)

My code :

```
import csv
#open your output file in append mode

with open('output.csv','a+') as out:
    outwriter = csv.writer(out,dialect='excel')

    #write your headers
    outwriter.writerow(['data','rssi','time'])

    with open("data2.txt") as f:

            #list that holds each row
            csvlines=[]

            #labels you wanna keep
            keep=["u'dataFrame'","u'rssi'","u'timestamp'"]
            lines=f.readlines()

            #split at first : character
            lines = map(lambda x:x.split(':',1),lines)
            for line in lines:
                if line[0].strip() in keep:

                    csvlines.append(line[1].strip())
                #clean from unnecessary characters
                csvlines=map(lambda x:x.replace("u'","").replace("'","").replace(",",""),csvlines)
                #write it to csv and then reset it for the next file.
                if(len(csvlines)==3):
                   print "writing"
                   print csvlines
                   outwriter.writerow(csvlines)
                   csvlines=[]
```

My intention was to filter out specific data into csv file but it works for the second sample data I showed above and does not work for the first sample data.. it looks like they are just identical to me. Why is first one not working with this code?